# Adding java.util.Date as input for flow throws error date is not annotated or on the whitelist

Tags: corda

I am trying to add java.util.Date type variable as input to a flow. It doesn't accept and complains about not being serializable. How can I fix this. I saw that Date is not part of the DefaultSerializable class.

I observed that I cant even retreive Date type fields from vault. See the same error.

Is there a way we can make java util Date Serializable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you've to whitelist java.util.Date or whatever date you are using.

Create a Folder Structure like:

> resources>META-INF>
>       services>
>       net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist.txt 
>       under your services folder.

Now create a class as below and make it implement SerializationWhitelist and in the getWhitelist method put in names of all the classes you want to whitelist.

```
public class SerializationWhiteList implements SerializationWhitelist {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<Class<?>> getWhitelist() {
        return ImmutableList.of(HashSet.class, java.sql.Date.class, java.util.Date.class,
                Instant.class);
    }
}
```

In your SerializationWhitelist.txt file mention the full class name including the package name 
eg: com.sc.corda.node.util.SerializationWhiteList.

At the time of bootstrapping, Corda looks for the classes mentioned in here will whitelist them

Comment: Yep - see example here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin/blob/release-V3/cordapp/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist and here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin/blob/release-V3/cordapp/src/main/kotlin/com/template/App.kt#L64.